# How much of the Lannister army is left as of S07E04?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In "The Spoils of War" (*Game of Thrones*, S07E04), lord Tarly mentions that the gold they *secured* from Highgarden is through the gates of King's Landing. But what about the army?

Lord Tarly says:

> We need to get the last of these wagons over the Blackwater Rush
>   before nightfall.

So we can assume that some of the army (if not most) is also at King's Landing. Or is this assumption incorrect? Is it stated or clearly obvious how much of the army is left?

Comment: Though I've heard that the soldiers seen in the "Third Battle of Tumbleton" are the "tail-end" of the Lannister-Tarly force I don't think we'll get a decisive answer to this question until at least the next episode (S07E05), but it would seem that the majority of the army made it to Kings Landing.

Comment: I've rewatched this multiple times. Does it really make sense, that Jamie and much of the gold and captures are at the 'tail-end' of the army? Also Jamie mentioned, that the army force could handle the attack.... until the dragons showed up. For me the strength of the lannister army is way to overpowered given the facts in the books. Also The force of Euron Greyjoy comes out of nowhere, but thats another thing...

Comment: @shock_gone_wild I also feel the same. You would assume that Jamie would like to ride up front and get all the praise, but maybe due to his latest character developments he just wants to see his people (army) to safety.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In "The Queen's Justice" (*Game of Thrones*, S07E03), Tyrion describes the Lannister army at Casterly Rock:

> TYRION: No one has ever taken the rock. The Lannister army is still the army my father built - well trained and well provisioned - **ten thousand men, at least**.
> <sub>—"The Queen's Justice", *Game of Thrones* (S07E03)</sub>

In "Stormborn" (*Game of Thrones*, S07E02), Jaime speaks with Randyll Tarly, a conversation which leads Randyll to become Jaime's general, and to have a bunch of other lords of the Reach join their forces with the royal (Lannister) army.

> JAIME: (TO RANDYLL TARLY) Thank you for coming. The other lords of the Reach look to you for guidance, now more than ever. They might not have come if you hadn't.
>
> [...]
>
> JAIME: I want you to be my ranking general in the wars to come, I want you to swear allegiance to Cersei and I want you to help me destroy her enemies - all her enemies.
> <sub>—"Stormborn", *Game of Thrones* (S07E02)</sub>

In other words, the Lannister army at Casterly Rock gives us an indication that they have an army of at the very least ten thousand (considering those ten thousand abandoned Casterly Rock). Combined with Tarly and the rest of the lords of the Reach's forces, we have a sizeable army. Don't forget about the Riverlands which Jaime secured last season, their armies are sworn to the crown, too.

In "You Win or You Die" (*Game of Thrones*, S01E07), Tywin talks about how he will split up sixty thousand Lannister soldiers, and in Season 2 we learn that Renly's armies (comprised mainly of The Reach and some of the Stormlands) exceeds a hundred thousand soldiers. These are all outdated, War of the Five Kings numbers, but given that the lords of the Reach and the Lannisters have only grown in success since (except the Tyrells, who defected and got slaughtered at Highgarden), we can make a safe assumption that the **sixty thousand Lannister soldiers** is the lowest bound for a total Lannister soldier count.

The Lannister-Tyrell forces at the end of "The Spoils of War" (*Game of Thrones*, S07E04) seem to be a thin amount of the tail-end of the train.

> RANDYLL: All the gold safely through the gates at King's Landing.
>
> JAIME: We need to get the last of these wagons over the Blackwater Rush before nightfall. If the head of the line is ambushed, the tail will never be able to reinforce it in time.
>
> JAIME: Well, we are stretched a bit thin.
> <sub>—"The Spoils of War", *Game of Thrones* (S07E04)</sub>

So, from the dialogue, we can infer that this is but a small percentage of the "ten thousand men, at least" of the Lannister army that left Casterly Rock. Also at a glance, it doesn't look like much more than a thousand (total Lannister + Tarly).

It's also worth noting that, because they are ruling over Seven Kingdoms, the Lannister armies are spread out around a lot of Westeros. We even saw direct evidence of this in "Hands of Gold" (*Game of Thrones*, S07E01), in a scene in which Arya Stark stumbles upon a group of Lannister men in the Riverlands.

[image]

> ARYA: What are you doing in the Riverlands?
>
> SOLDIER: There's been some trouble with the Freys up at the Twins, so, **we're part of the army** that's been sent to keep the peace.
> <sub>—"Hands of Gold", *Game of Thrones* (S07E01)</sub>

If you consider Houses that are sworn to the Lannisters (indirectly, by being sworn to the crown), then a reasonable estimate of the total army is close to a hundred thousand, given that the Tyrells have been wiped out, the Reach's hundred thousand diminished greatly, but combined with the Lannister army creeps back up to somewhere near a hundred thousand. The Lannister army alone is tough to estimate, but given that they are comfortable sending armies up to the Twins, and given that the Casterly Rock army alone is ten thousand, and given that when they were less successful than they are now, they even had sixty thousand, you can assume that even after the massacre at the end of "The Spoils of War" (*Game of Thrones*, S07E04), **they have at least sixty thousand soldiers** in total.

Worth noting that Tyrion points out to Daenerys that **she still has the largest armies**:

> DAENERYS: My allies are gone. They've been taken from me while I've been sitting here on this island
>
> TYRION: You still have the largest armies.
> <sub>—"The Spoils of War", *Game of Thrones* (S07E04)</sub>

We know that the Unsullied are eight thousand strong, at least, and the Dothraki's numbers are hard to put a number on, but khalasars have been known to be over fifty thousand strong (Drogo's was forty thousand strong), and since the Dothraki who crossed the Narrow Sea seem to be a congregation of many khalasars (the entire horde), we could be talking about a hundred thousand Dothraki. This doesn't help us immensely, but is there as an added reference to army numbers in the show.

Comment: +1 Well sourced answer to a difficult question (one I have been asking myself since Monday!). It's not the whole picture, but it shows that despite Daenerys resounding victory at Tumbleton she still has a long way to go

Comment: @KallumTanton It's an unfolding event in the show, at the moment, we can only make estimates based on what we've been told, but we'll probably have a more accurate, concrete idea when (or if) it comes up in one of the following episodes - at which point I'll update the answer with the most up-to-date, referenced information.

Comment: Greyworm was dismayed when taking Casterly Rock, there were too few defenders. 1,000 men could easily hold a well defended position for some time from the Unsullied. I doubt the majority of the Lanister army was left to defend the rock.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier You *should* doubt that, because the entire point of that sequence of that episode was to show us, the audience, the sudden twist that Jaime mobilised the army at Casterly Rock, leaving only a small garrison behind, to go an take Highgarden (together with the Tarly + other Reach bannermen's forces). / I hope you didn't get the idea that I claimed `the majority of the Lannister army was left to defend the rock`, because I made no such claim, in fact I made the opposite claim: `"ten thousand men, at least" of the Lannister army that left Casterly Rock`

Comment: I'm not sure if your estimate about the khalasar is well thought out. Tyrion could be just wrong, he hasn't been to Westeros in quite a while and Varys's spies have been feeding them ("the court" of Daenerys) no or possibly even false information.

Comment: @GhotiandChips: Dude, ten thousand apologies, I read _"ten thousand men, at least" of the Lannister army that left Casterly Rock_ as _"ten thousand men, at least" of the Lannister army left **at** Casterly Rock_. Tots my bad dude!

Comment: @Tom The estimation of the Dothraki is irrespective of Tyrion's claim that she has the larger armies - the Dothraki is not one Khalasar, but *all* khalasars. In "Book of the Stranger" (S06E04), she emerges from Vaes Dothrak (the temple of the Dosh Khaleen) after having burned half a dozen khals (each representing a khalasaar). If each khalasaar only represents an anemic estimate of 20,000 Dothraki, that is still at least 100,000 total. Obviously, it's not certain they *all* came with her, but an estimate of 100,000 is completely safe. edit: Imdb lists 5 khals in that episode.

Comment: This is a nice answer but I think you are missing a substantial part of the equation that will reduce your overall count. The Battle of Blackwater Bay involving Stannis's army of 200+ ships happened after that 60,000 S1E7 count. By all accounts, that battle would have been won by Stannis if not for the Tyrell (and Tywin) reinforcements so I don't think it's unlikely that the Lannister's suffered some significant casualties. It's been awhile since I've read the books but I remember feeling as though the Lannisters were more encumbered and struggling to retain power after that battle.

Comment: @DanK `but I think you are missing a substantial part` - It's great to see people critically thinking, but you may find that I did not actually miss this point. I refer you to the paragraph where I reference the 60k number, where I say: `These are all outdated, War of the Five Kings numbers` - So, I acknowledge the simple fact that warfare, whether on the winning or losing side, causes your military numbers to atrophy. I then go on to say that the 10k Lannisters at Casterly Rock, plus whatever troops they gained thanks to becoming royalty, essentially negates that loss.

Comment: @DanK According to [book canon](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Military_strength), Tywin lost 3,000 troops during his entire campaign in the War of the Five Kings, and the siege of King's Landing that you reference. I didn't use book canon in my answer, but it's the closest number I could find for the issue you bring up - needless to say, 3,000 troops doesn't really put a dent in the number I estimated, especially when you consider the added troops from the three years that have passed and gaining the throne, etc. If anything it should be higher, but I'm a fan of safe, low estimates.

Comment: I think it's pretty uncertain how substantial a force was still escorting the supply train, but, regardless, there is the bulk of the armies still available, and the catastrophic loss would be the commander of the armies (Jamie) and their #1 battlefield general, in rank and skill (Tarley). Who is going to lead the (land) armies?

Comment: `and the catastrophic loss would be the commander of the armies`. Yep. Bronn's "flee to King's Landing, you're a commander not a bloody foot soldier" was like music to my Rome: Total War loving ears. It's like, dramatically it's "badass" for Jaime to stay put, and it certainly boosts morale, but tactically it makes 0 sense, and probably something the book would stay away from. Idem Dickon and Randyll.

Comment: @GhotiandChips That 3000 number is an interesting one... I was thinking it was significantly higher. In that case, I'll defer to your research... Good answer.

Comment: I don't think we'll be getting a better answer than this! Incredible amount of research, thank you and well done. If you would update your answer if we ever have a more clearly stated number that would be very kind. Thank you once again.